# adjust distance between nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, uml

I try below code to implement a simple uml sequence diagram, it works but two things would like to improve:

1. The message back description text should change to above left.
2. The node distance should adjust according to text width below. (current code use a define to adjust it manually).

code:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{
    class/.style={%
        inner sep=2pt,
        minimum width=1ex,
    },
    arr/.style={%
        draw,-stealth
    },
}
\newcommand{\actor}[3][]{%
  \node[class,#1] (#2) {#3};
  \draw [line width=1] (#2.south west) -- (#2.south east);
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\fontsize{5}{6}\selectfont]
 \def\nodes{%
   A/2cm/jack,
   B/2cm/mary,
   C/2cm/john
 }
 \def\links{%
   A/B/message one,
   B/C/message two loooooooooooong,
   C/A/message three
 } 

 \foreach \name/\pos/\desc [count=\i from 0,remember=\name as \prev] in \nodes {%
   \ifnum \i=0
      \actor[]{\name}{\desc};
   \else
      \actor[right=\pos of \prev]{\name}{\desc};
   \fi
   \message{debugme  \i -> \prev};   
 } 

 \def\dy{-.3cm}
 \foreach \from/\to/\desc [count=\i] in \links {
     \draw[arr] ([yshift=\i*\dy]\from.south) -- coordinate(P) ([yshift=\i*\dy]\to.south)
         node[pos=0,above right] {\tiny \desc};
 }

\foreach \name/\pos/\desc in \nodes {%
   \draw[dashed] (\name.south) -- (\name|-P);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

With elementary code, which for nodes placement use Ti*k*Z libraries `chains` and `positioning`:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 5mm and 22mm,
  start chain = going right,
arr/.style = {-{Straight Barb[scale=0.8]}, semithick},
lbl/.style = {font=\scriptsize\linespread{0.84}\relax, 
              inner sep=1pt, fill=white, 
              text width=22mm, align=center, above},
  N/.style = {font=\footnotesize, 
        append after command = {\pgfextra{\let\LN\tikzlastnode
                \draw[ultra thick, line cap=round]
                        (\LN.south west) -- (\LN.south east);
                                        }% end \pgfextra
                                },% end after command
        on chain
             },
                        ]
    \foreach \i [count=\j]  in {Jack, Mary, John}
{
\node (n\j) [N] {\i};

\draw[very thin, densely dashed] (n\j.south) -- ++ (0,-1.7);
}
\path   (n1.south)  -- ++ (0,-5mm) coordinate (A)
                    -- ++ (0,-5mm) coordinate (B)
                    -- ++ (0,-5mm) coordinate (C);
\draw[arr]  (A) -- node[lbl] {message one} (A -| n2);
\draw[arr]  (B -| n2) -- node[lbl] {message two loooooooooooong} (B -| n3);
\draw[arr]  (C -| n3) -- node[lbl] {message three} (C);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**

- Apparently I misunderstood the question (and underestimate what OP is after ...), - - MWE below now fulfill OP demands

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\dx}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 5mm,
arr/.style = {-{Straight Barb[scale=0.8]}, semithick},
lbl/.style = {font=\small,above},
  N/.style = {font=\small,
        append after command = {\pgfextra{\let\LN\tikzlastnode
                \draw[ultra thick, line cap=round]
                        (\LN.south west) -- (\LN.south east);
                                        }% end \pgfextra
                                },% end after command
             },
                        ]
\def\dy{5mm}

\node (n1) [N] {Jacki};
\setlength{\dx}{\widthof{message two}}
\node (n2) [N, right=\dx of n1] {Mary};

\setlength{\dx}{\widthof{message two is very long, consequently distance between nodes too}}
\node (n3) [N, right=\dx of n2] {John};
    \foreach \i in {1,2,3}
\draw[very thin, densely dashed] (n\i.south) -- ++ (0,-21mm);

\coordinate[below=of n1.south] (A);
\coordinate[below=of A] (B);
\coordinate[below=of B] (C);

\draw[arr]  (A) -- node[lbl] {message one} (A -| n2);
\draw[arr]  (B -| n2) -- node[lbl] {message two is very long, consequently distance between nodes too} (B -| n3);
\draw[arr]  (C -| n3) -- node[lbl] {message three} (C);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good answer to use chain, but the distance between chain nodes is the same, how to make it adjust distance per text message below the nodes?

Comment: @lucky1928, why you do this? Diagram, as is shown is quite cute,  isn't it?? With your desired design it will not be anymore (to my opinion, of course). However, this is not hard to achieve, you need just to measure text width ... and than use it for distance between nodes.

Comment: Yes, I like this cute graph. the idea is user can add objects and many links then get a longer graph to show the relation ship. if links increased, then calculate the distance will need more effort. so wish to implement auto adjust by coding.

Comment: @lucky1928, see addendum to your answer. It will appear soon.